# S3 bucket script to add timestamp in filename on upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a way to add a timestamp in every file that is uploaded to an S3 bucket, Amazon-side. There is, of course, an option to do this client-side before the upload, but I don't think this is as nice and clean as it would be to have some script to run in the bucket itself everytime a new file is uploaded. I didn't find anything in the docs, though.

Comment: You want to add timestamp as the name of the file or you want to add a time stamp to the meta data of the file?

Comment: The idea is to add a timestamp as a prefix of the file name, thus making every file unique to avoid file overwriting.

Comment: S3 already has a mechanism to avoid overwriting -- [object versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html) -- which returns a unique version id with each upload.  What you are proposing is spooky action at a distance -- once you upload a file, you have absolutely no idea what its object key is because it would no longer be what you used to upload it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no capability** within Amazon S3 to change the Key (filename) of a file based upon upload time.

Given that your desire is to **avoid name conflicts**, some choices are:

- Use a **unique GUID or a timestamp** to name the file when uploading. This will avoid naming conflicts.
- Upload the file to Bucket A, then use a **Lambda function triggered on ObjectCreation to copy the object** to Bucket B with a unique name based on timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a lambda function handling the ObjectCreated event. See [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html).

Not sure that works though.

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem is there is already a lambda listening to this bucket, meant to run a function completely unrelated to renaming the file. I could, of course, create a separate bucket and make a lambda listen to it only to rename the file and send the renamed file to the existing bucket, but this seems to over...